# Como fazer um request com curl

Tags: php, libcurl

Olá, pessoal, eu estou envolvido em um projeto e preciso fazer um request com curl para obter dados de uma api. Mas eu nunca usei curl em php dessa forma. Podem me ajudar?

`curl -X GET https://jsonodds.com/api/odds/nfl -H "JsonOdds-API-Key: yourapikey"`

Pelo o que eu entendi ele ta pedindo um get com a key da api, mas quando eu ponho assim:

```
'https://jsonodds.com/api/odds?JsonOdds-API-Key=11111111111111
```

("11111111111111" equivale a minha chave)

Ele da erro 401 dizendo que meu acesso foi negado por credenciais inválidas.
Me ajudem, por favor. Obrigado!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
curl -X GET https://jsonodds.com/api/odds/nfl -H "JsonOdds-API-Key: yourapikey"
```

---

**Tradução:**

- O `-X` (maiúsculo) indica uma requisição customizada, neste caso `GET`, nem havia motivo para isto. *Por curiosidade o `-x` (minusculo) indica um proxy (logo `-x usr:senha@127.0.0.1:80`)*.
- O `-H` é um `HEADER`, um cabeçalho, neste caso com o valor de `JsonOdds-API-Key: yourapikey`.
- O `https://jsonodds.com/api/odds/nfl` é o link mesmo, que vai se conectar. :P

---

**Agora para fazer isto no PHP, na mesma ordem:**

```
// Iniciamos a função do CURL:
$ch = curl_init('https://jsonodds.com/api/odds/nfl');

curl_setopt_array($ch, [

    // Equivalente ao -X:
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',

    // Equivalente ao -H:
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'JsonOdds-API-Key: yourapikey'
    ],

    // Permite obter o resultado
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
]);

$resposta = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Bem, assim me ajudou bastante, então obrigado!

Answer (score 7):

Devo-te já dizer que o erro vai permanecer ao usares as mesmas credênciais (aparentemente as credênciais estão inválidas), para fazeres um curl com php podes:

```
$url = 'https://jsonodds.com/api/odds?JsonOdds-API-Key=';
$apiKey = '11111111111111';
$curl = curl_init($url.$apiKey);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
$return = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $return; // a tua resposta em string json
$arrResp = json_decode($return, true); // o teu json de resposta convertido para array
```

Nota que estás a usar exatamente a mesma ferramenta mas por um meio deferente (php) em vez de ser na shell como tens na pergunta.

Vou deixar um exemplo funcional (que não dê erro 401) em baixo:

```
$url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Miguel-Frazao/us-data/master/zip_codes_us.json';
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
$return = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $return; // a tua resposta em string json
$arrResp = json_decode($return, true); // o teu array criado a partir do json de resposta
```

Comment: Obrigado, era isso mesmo que eu queria! Assim eu consigo entender.

Comment: De nada @Krint, ainda bem que resolveste